# Formula to return the sum of a range in Excel for certain rows in a different column

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I would like to use formula to return the sum of cells from column B where cell value in column A is equal to a certain week number. The table is below. For example if Week = 1 the SUM would be 40; Week = 2 SUM = 110 ,etc.

A:Week B:Values

A B

1 10

1 20

1 30

1 40

2 11

2 22

2 33

2 44

3 12

3 24

3 36

3 48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF` for this, e.g.

`=SUMIF(A:A,1,B:B)`

that sums all values in column B where column A = 1